# System.Timers.Timer in Windows Service or Console Application

Tags: vb.net, timer

I'm writing a vb.net .net 4.0 application and am having issues getting the timer to elapse.  Can someone help tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've troubleshooted the main application so much that I decided to try to make it work in a new project and can't seem to get this to work.

Thanks!

```
Module Module1

Public Timer As New System.Timers.Timer

Sub Main()


    AddHandler Timer.Elapsed, AddressOf Timer_Tick
    Timer.AutoReset = True
    Timer.Interval = 1000
    Timer.Start()



    Console.WriteLine("Timer Started")


End Sub

Sub Timer_Tick(source As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("TimerTick")
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: That code is going to execute and then close the console window almost instantaneously, the timer will never even have a chance to tick. If you add  "Do Until (Console.ReadKey.Key = ConsoleKey.Escape) : Loop" as the last line of your Main() sub, you'll see the timer gets a chance to tick and writes as expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `Main()` keeps running or your process will terminate immediately.

You can use `Console.ReadLine()` (if you have a console) or `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)`.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)` does not appear to work in vb.net,and I've never had to do this before in a windows service...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know reason why your code doesn't work. But you can use functions cycle to do this same work.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
            Console.WriteLine("Timer Started")
            Timer_start()
        End Sub


        Function Timer_start()
            Timer_Tick()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        End Function


        Function Timer_Tick()
            Console.WriteLine("TimerTick")                
            Timer_start()
        End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main

Timer.Interval = 60000  ' one minute
Timer.Enabled

' do stuff

Do until (Some condition, like a stop flag to stop looping and end program)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
Loop

End

Timer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles Timer.Elapsed

Timer.enabled = False

' do stuff

Timer.Enabled = True
End Sub
```